# Switch contents of display from laptop to external monitor

Tags: display, screen, mission-control

I use my mac screen and an external monitor.

Is it possible to swap the entire contents of my laptop with what is on my external monitor?

So below I would like to swap the contents of my monitor from the man to the sheep (and any other app which is open on and one one screen whould then be swapped to another)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

fn ⌘ ↓ - combines the contents of both screens into one